# Problem with processing cyrillic symbols in python

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, cyrillic

I faced with problem processing cyrillic symbols. I have a dataframe with 2 columns, on of them contains cyrillic symbols. Example of this pandas dataframe:
`count                                               word
0     2193                                                u''
1      543                                          u'\u0440'
2      397                                    u'\u043d\u0430'
3      392                                          u'\u0438'
4      359            u'\u0411\u0430\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0441'
5      199                                          u'\u0432'
6      178                                          u'\u0441'
7      139                                    u'\u043f\u043e'
8      133                                            u'VISA'
9      122   u'\u043f\u043e\u0434\u043a\u043b\u044e\u0447\...`

But, for example, If I use `print()` just for one string, such as `print(u'\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e')`, I have this output: `можно`. It means, that `print()` can rightly interprete cyrillic symbols.
How can I print my dataframe with normal displaying cyrillic symbols? Is it possible to convert this pandas dataframe to cyrillic symbols and write it into `.csv` format?  Thanks for any suggestions.
BR,
Vladimir.

Comment: This is how Unicode strings look like in Python 2. It's the `repr()` format, which is ASCII-only. In Python 3, you will see most characters rendered literally, only non-printable characters use the escape notation with `\x..` and `\u....`. Can you upgrade to Python 3?

Comment: How *exactly* did you generate that view?  I created a DataFrame with that data and it display correctly in Python 2.7.14 in a UTF8 IDE, and with ? for non-ASCII in a `cp437` Windows console.  Use the command `chcp 1251` to switch the default encoding and the Cyrillic displays correctly.  I'm not getting `repr()` versions at all.  Could it be you have the *literal text* `u'\u0440'` (length 9) and not the length 1 Unicode string `р`?

Comment: Hi @lenz , I used virtual env Anaconda-4.1.1 with python 3.4

Comment: Hi @MarkTolonen, I used CentOS 7 with virtual environment Anaconda-4.4.1 python 3.4, running this script in shell. I generated this view just like that: `columns=['count','word']
df = pd.read_csv("/home/jup-user/testdb/scripts/data/file.csv", names=columns)`
Data shown in `.log` file, I also changed it to UTF8, but unfortunately it's not working for my dataframe.

Comment: I think Mark's suspicion is probably right. It looks a lot like the data were exported using Python 2 at some earlier stage, and now you have literal quotes and backslashes in your cell strings. You should try to restore the original values using `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: @lenz,  thanks for your attention to my issue. I guess that problem in reading text file with coded symbols. For example, I wrote string `string = '\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e'` into textfile and I have got cyrillic string in output file. But when I wrote this coded symbols in textfile via Notepad and tried read it in python script, I recieved indentity coded symbols `'\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e'`

Comment: Well, yes. When you read a text file, it isn't parsed like source code.

Comment: @lenz, `encoded = sfile.encode().decode('unicode_escape')` - this helped me to solve this problem.